# Can I create a JSP from dynamically generated XML?

Tags: java, xml, jsp, xslt, jstl

I want to generate a JSP using XSLT and `<x:transform>` tag. But I don't have an XML-file on my file system, and I can't import it like: `<c:import url="./xml/MyXml.xml" var="xmldoc"/>`. It is generated dynamically in Java code and set as String to request attribute.
I try do it like this:

```
<div id="mydiv">
    <c:set var="xmldoc">
       <c:out value="${requestScope.someXmlString}"/>
    </c:set>
    <c:import url="./xsl/MyStylesheet.xsl" var="xsltdoc"/>
    <x:transform xml="${xmldoc}" xslt="${xsltdoc}"/>
</div>
```

or

```
<div id="mydiv">
    <c:set var="xmldoc" value="${requestScope.someXmlString}">           
    <c:import url="./xsl/MyStylesheet.xsl" var="xsltdoc"/>
    <x:transform xml="${xmldoc}" xslt="${xsltdoc}"/>
</div>
```

But it's not working. It seems `<x:transform>` expects only a xml-document (not a string). How can I do it? Or is there another way to do this?

Comment: According [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_xml_transform_tag.htm) it is supposed to be working. I believe, that issue is in `c:import` directive. Just for testing purposes try to use absolute URL (f.e. `http://localhost:8080/myapp/xsl/MyStylesheet.xsl`), and if it works, then you may try to play with `${pageContext.servletContext.servletContextName}` or something like this.

Comment: Thanks. But I tried tested it like '<c:import url="./xsl/MyStylesheet.xsl" var="xsltdoc"/> <c:import url="./xsl/MyXml.xml" var="xmldoc"/> <x:transform xml="${xmldoc}" xslt="${xsltdoc}"/>'. And it worked. I think the reason is not to 'c:import'. But I'll try to play whis path more.

Comment: That's what I'm talking: instead of `<c:import url="./xsl/MyStylesheet.xsl" var="xsltdoc"/>` please try to use `<c:import url="http://localhost:8080/myapp/xsl/MyStylesheet.xsl" var="xsltdoc"/>` and see what happens.

Comment: Sorry. I accidentally posted a last post. I edited it.

Comment: see example http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_xml_data.htm

Answer (score 0):

You need not try and set the value you could directly refer the request value in your `<x:transform>` tag.

```
<x:transform xml="${requestScope.someXmlString}" xslt="${xsltdoc}"/>
```

By default jstl uses request scope. So if you set the value like request.setAttribute("someXmlString", xmlStr); then you could directly call

```
<x:transform xml="${someXmlString}" xslt="${xsltdoc}"/>
```

Both should work.